# Control electrical switch through external mechanism

Tags: switches

I am planning to control a water tank motor switch through some mechanical means( Since I am in a rented house, I am not allowed to change the electrical wiring for this. And the switch is in the ground floor, while I stay in the second floor. I am planning to control the switch from my house).

The switch is similar to this

[image]

I am looking for a mechanism in which there will be an external mechanical structure which will hit the switch to turn it on and off. It should retract after hitting the switch to allow manual control as well.

I know the solution has to be something similar to relays but I am not sure on the details.

Please help.

I would be thankful for any suggestions and ideas.

Regards,
Naveen

Comment: Wireless domotics supplier.

Comment: Relay with a manual override.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have described, you wish to press this switch into the on position, with some kind of device, just as you would by pressing it with your hand. A linear actuator would do the trick, but you would have to create some kind of cradle for it to sit in, and electronic circuit to control the actuator. 
I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Also a push solenoid would work, but again there would have to be a separate circuit for this, and the cradle to hold the device in

Comment: Hi James, you did understand my problem correctly! Thanks for suggesting possible solutions through linear actuators and solenoid. I'll dig deep into it to make this concept work.

Comment: No problem, I hope you manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this mechanism mechanical enough? http://odditymall.com/extravagant-light-switch-toggle

[image]